# I am trying to show 2 progress bars side by side but one of them is populating and the other is not even the code is in different js functions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Below is the code that I have tried in jsbin
[Code](http://jsbin.com/nesivonecu/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
 .background {
    fill: #DFEAFD;
  }

  .foreground {
    fill: #2E7AF9;
  }
.progress-meter {

  .background {
    fill: #DFEAFD;
  }

  .foreground {
    fill: #2E7AF9;
  }

  text {
    font-family: 'Georgia' sans-serif;
    font-size: 90px;
  }

  .text2 {
    font-family: 'Georgia' sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="completion-chart"></div>
<div class="completion-chart1"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js">

var test=function(){
var width = 120,
    height = 120,
    twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
    progress = 0,
    total = 100,
    formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(0)
    .innerRadius(30)
    .outerRadius(45)
;

var svg = d3.select(".completion-chart1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

    .attr('fill', '#2E7AF9')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var meter = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "progress-meter");

meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

var foreground = meter.append("path")
    .attr("class", "foreground");

var text = meter.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

var i = d3.interpolate(progress, 90/100);

    d3.transition().duration(1200).tween("progress", function () {
        return function (t) {
            progress = i(t);
            foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
            text.text(formatPercent(progress));
        };
    });
};

var test2=function(){
    var width = 120,
        height = 120,
        twoPi = 2 * Math.PI,
        progress = 0,
        total = 100,
        formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(0)
        .innerRadius(30)
        .outerRadius(45)
    ;

    var svg = d3.select(".completion-chart").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)

        .attr('fill', '#2E7AF9')
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var meter = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "progress-meter");

    meter.append("path")
        .attr("class", "background")
        .attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi));

    var foreground = meter.append("path")
        .attr("class", "foreground");

    var text = meter.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

    var i = d3.interpolate(progress, 90/100);

        d3.transition().duration(1200).tween("progress", function () {
            return function (t) {
                progress = i(t);
                foreground.attr("d", arc.endAngle(twoPi * progress));
                text.text(formatPercent(progress));
            };
        });
    };
    test();
    test2();
</script>
</body>
```

I am trying to show 2 progress bars side by side but one of them is populating and the other is not even the code is in different js functions
Below is the screenshot of the issue:

[Image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHleM.png)

Is there anything that I am missing or anything wrong with  my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `d3.transition().duration(1200)` you apply the transition to d3 itself, which only can have one transition at time. So if you call `d3.transition().duration(1200)` a second time, the first transition will be canceled and you will only get the transition on one of your progress-"bars".

Instead apply the transition to the meter-object itself by using

```
d3.select(meter).transition().duration(1200)
```